# Creating a simple Backbone.js application with two views: list and detail?

Tags: javascript, rest, backbone.js

I've been fighting with Backbone.js for days now trying to create something as simple as a page with two views, (1) a list of objects returned from a REST collection (`/api/v1/items/`) with links to (2) detailed views about each of the objects in the list from a REST resource (`/api/v1/items/1248`).

I've been trying to read documentation and tutorials, but I haven't really gotten that far at all. And the code I've managed to write looks like a mess, so I figure there is some easier way to do it. This should be a simple thing to do, shouldn't it? It's more or less a 1:1 mapping of a REST API to Backbone.js views.

My problem is that I don't really know how to construct the two views, one with information from the collection (`/api/v1/items/`) and one with information from the resource (`/api/v1/items/1248`). I pretty much can't get any further than retrieving the data from the models. I don't really know how the Views fit together with the Router (do I need a Router for this?), and I don't really know how to render the information on load in any decently looking fashion.

Comment: Yeah, I should probably have mentioned that. :) I updated the original post.

Comment: This question is probably the basis for 75% of backbone tutorials online, so unless you are going to post your code, we can't really help you.

Comment: your question is one of the reasons why I created a simple no database CRUD sample. It can be found [here](https://github.com/coding-idiot/BackboneCRUD).